# Place Image and Break Pages

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, align

I want to obtain the following format:

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
endofpage
image
newpage
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

I have three pages in total. The image occupies whole page and the text in newpage is continuation of paragraph of previous `Text`.

Even though I place

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
\begin{image}
\end{image}
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

I get something like

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
newpage
image
```

This is clearly what I don't want. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
\pagebreak
\begin{image}
\end{image}
\pagebreak
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

Comment: It would be better to use `\clearpage`, specially after the image has been included, since `\clearpage` flushes images before starting the new page.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{float}
Text
Text
Text
Text
\pagebreak
\begin{image}[H]
\end{image}
\pagebreak
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

Works better. Read somewhere!